# Getting Android bootstrap socket crash

Tags: java, appium

I am executing the appium automation test suite on a single device and get an android bootstrap socket crashed error:
    `read error : erroconnreset.`

What can be the possible cause of this error? I heard this error occurs on parallel device automation but mine is on single device only.

Comment: What is the port number and OS you are using? A bug referring to this was created and closed on the appium github repository https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/7930

Comment: In my case OS is windows . Using appium version 1.5 and bootstrap port by default is I guess 4724